# Bootstrap: Radio button toggle coloring

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

I am trying to create an on/off button toggle with Bootstrap.  When "On" is selected I want the background to be green, and I want the "Off" button to be grayed out and transparent.  When "Off" is selected I want it to be red and I want "On" to be deselected.  All of the examples I've found deal with disabled buttons, but I don't want to disable either of the buttons.  I know how to implement the colors and transparency in CSS, but I don't know how I can implement what I want by using CSS selectors with Bootstrap.  Do I have to make my own CSS classes for this or does Bootstrap have something built in?

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/UltraSonja/4pbpmqgu/

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary green">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="RTTOn" autocomplete="off">ON</input>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary red">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="RTTOff" autocomplete="off">OFF</input>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do.

```js
$('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');

  if ($(this).find('.btn-green').size() > 0) {
    $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-red');
  }

  $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');

});
```

```css
.btn-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.btn-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container wrap">
  <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-green">ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default active">OFF</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without Javascript?

Comment: I've copied all of this into an HTML file - and it doesn't work?!