# Button functionality malfunctions when added to AngularJS app

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684070/bootstrap-radio-button-toggle-coloring/31684575#31684575) which functions perfectly fine outside of my Angular app.  When I try to add it to my app, its functionality breaks.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="JsonController as jsonCtrl">
        <div class="cluster" ng-repeat="cluster in flats.blah.CLUSTERS">
            <h4 class="cluster-title row">{{cluster.name}}</h4>
            <div class="center">
              <div class="container wrap">
                  <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-green">ON</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default active">OFF</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**json-controller.js**

```
(function() {   

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('JsonController', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('flat.json')
                .then(function(res) {
                    $scope.flats = res.data;
                });
        });
})();
```

`json-controller.js` reads in(?) a JSON file from my workspace so that I can access it via AngularJS.
The weird part is, when I use a different controller with a hard-coded data model inside the controller, the button works.  So I know the problem is occurring when I include it in the Angular app, but I don't know why.  Any insight would be great.  I'll provide updates as I try to solve this.

Here is a controller it works with:

**working-controller.js**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('WorkingController', WorkingController);

    function WorkingController() {

        this.item = data;
    }

    var data == // ... hard-code data model
})();
```

I know the syntax is different for the controllers, but even when they have the same syntax the problem persists.  I should probably make my controller syntax consistent anyway.

EDIT:

I should also note that other functionality breaks too, such as popovers.  I implemented the button and popover function in a separate jQuery file.  Maybe there is a discrepancy between the JSON and the jQuery?  Am I missing a library dependency?

Comment: What does `console.log(res)` after reading the file say? Is the data getting fetched properly there?

Comment: @Fissio It gives a success `Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`, and I can verify this because I am getting the expected data when I use the `{{cluster.name}}` Angular expression.  I would provide the JSON, but I don't think that would be very help and it contains some sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your button action into a directive.
You can perform it without Jquery, just by using `ngClass` directive, and data-binding.

**Directive :**

```
(function(){



'use strict';

function toggle() {

    function link(scope, elm, attr, ctrl){

        angular.element(elm).on('click', function(){
            scope.on = !scope.on;
            scope.off = !scope.off;
            scope.$digest();
        });

    }


    var directive = {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: link,
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: {
            on: "=",
            off: "="
        }
    };

    return directive;

}

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('toggle', toggle);

})();
```

With the template :

**template :**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
    <button class="btn btn-lg" ng-class="{'btn-success':on, 'btn-default':!on}">ON</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg" ng-class="{'btn-danger':off, 'btn-default':!off}">OFF</button>
  </div>
```

**Controller :**

```
(function() {   

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('JsonController', function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.activeOn = true;
            $scope.activeOff = false;

            $http.get('flat.json')
                .then(function(res) {
                    $scope.flats = res.data;
                });
        });
})();
```

**HTML :**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="JsonController as jsonCtrl">
        <div class="cluster" ng-repeat="cluster in flats.blah.CLUSTERS">
            <h4>Name : {{cluster.name}}</h4>
            <div class="center">
              <div class="container wrap">
                <toggle on="activeOn" off="activeOff"></toggle>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div> 
</body>
```

And here is my flat.json sample :

```
{
   "blah": {
      "CLUSTERS": [
         {
            "name":"toto"
         },
         {
            "name": "titi"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah hah, directives.  That is something I definitely need to learn about.  Thank you.

Comment: Now the question is can you do this for popovers?  :P

Comment: Yep, just bind action with `mouseover` event for example